# Understanding the Invariance Property Proof of MLE

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

There are multiple versions of this question on CV and many proofs are given but I did not fully understand the proof (technique) yet.

**Theorem.**
If $$\hat\theta = \operatorname*{argsup}_{\theta\in\Theta} L(\theta, x)$$ exists, then for any function $g:\Theta\rightarrow\Lambda$ it holds that $\hat\lambda:=g(\hat\theta)$ is the MLE of $\lambda:=g(\theta)$.

**Proof.** Put $\tilde L(\lambda,x):=\sup\limits_{\theta\in\Theta:g(\theta)=\lambda}L(\theta,x)$.

Then
$$\begin{align*}
\hat\lambda &= \operatorname*{argsup}_{\lambda\in\Lambda} \tilde L(\lambda,x)\\
&= \operatorname*{argsup}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\sup_{\theta\in\Theta:g(\theta)=\lambda}L(\theta,x)\\
&= \ ?\\
&= g\left(\operatorname*{argsup}_{\theta\in\Theta}L(\theta,x)\right)\\
&= g(\hat\theta).
\end{align*}$$

Questions:

- Why is $g$ not required to be measurable?
- Why is $\hat\lambda = \operatorname*{argsup}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\tilde L(\lambda,x)$?
- What happens at "?" step?
- (is this proof correct?)

Comment: The mathematical notation might be obscuring the fundamental simplicity of this result: namely, $g$ merely is a way of *renaming* the optimal value(s) of the parameter.

Comment: I think this is exactely what confuses me... The notion is clear to me and if I think about it makes sense, especially if one considers one-to-one $g$. However, I struggle to write it down in a formal correct way. This may not be the best analogy but when I was a first year calculus student, I also thought that $\sup f(x) = f(\sup x)$ makes totally sense but is not true. This exercise reminds me of this example, especially since it feels like interchanging function and supremum at some point...

Comment: Interesting example.  The problem with equating $\sup f$ with $f(\sup x),$ of course, is that $\sup x$ might not even be in the domain of $f$!